# Comparing content of a cell array with a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have the following 1-by-3 cell arrays:

```
Y = {[2 3 4 5 8],[1 2 5 7 8],[3 4 7 8]}
```

and the following 1-by-8 vector:

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

Using a form of logical index, I will like to compare the vector with each content of the cell array. For instance, comparing X with `Y(1,1)` would give the following:

```
[0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1]
```

likewise, comparing `X` with `Y(1,2)` will give the following:

```
[1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]
```

And comparing `X` with `Y(1,3)` will give the following:

```
[0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
```

Hence, I should have the following output:

```
[0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
```

Grateful for any form of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to each cell's contents:

```
result = cellfun(@(c) ismember(X, c), Y, 'UniformOutput', false); % gives cell array
result = vertcat(result{:}); % vertically concatenate cells' contents into a matrix
```